# How can I secure Jenkins port 8080 with SSL under apache2 in ubuntu 18.04 Server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, jenkins, https

I have been able to successfully install and configure Apache2 server to served on HTTPS. I have been having issues getting Jenkins to use the same SSL certificates and run on Secured port 443. This is my configurations and please, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I have the server currently serving a static WordPress site which launches successfully on https port 80 or 443. I also have Jenkins serving successfully on the route of the server but with port 8080.

Is there any way I can get Jenkins to serve right under the Apache2 server like
jenkins.server.com/jenkins instead of jenkins.server.com:8080?

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName jenkins.server.com
        ServerAlias www.jenkins.server.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jenkins.server.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on

        # SSL certificate and keys. Edit paths to whereever your SSL files are located
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.server.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.server.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RewriteEngine On
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

        ProxyPass / http://jenkins.server.com:8080 nocanon
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RewriteEngine On
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

        ProxyPass / http://jenkins.server.com:8080 nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse / http://jenkins.server.com:8080

        <Proxy http://jenkins.server.com:8080/*>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you also share if there is any error logs? Is `mod_proxy` enabled for Apache2? Is there any `--prefix=..` set to `JENKINS_ARGS`?

Comment: in the /etc/default/jenkins, I have no prefix set on Jenkins this is the args I have within Jenkins and also mod_proxy enables successfully for Apache2. I get the feedback as already enabled.
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT" which runs jenkins successfully on the https://jenkins.server.com:8080. I only get an error as certificate not valid for SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by modifying the generated file by Apache2 with the name 000-default-le-ssl.conf under /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf
This file was generated automatically and I modified the proxy settings.

I also had to maintain "localhost" instead of jenkins.server.com even though localhost will not launch Jenkins in the browser.

This is my updated and working file...

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName jenkins.server.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
        ProxyRequests     Off
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

        # Local reverse proxy authorization override
        # Most unix distribution deny proxy by default (ie /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf in Ubuntu)
        <Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.server.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.server.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```